# How do websites send email when new answers is posted to question

Tags: .net, email

How do websites send email when new answers is posted to question like if you answer this question, I will get automated email that my question has an answer?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the code that sends email, or are you asking for techniques - for example, do they send the emails immediately, or do they check every few minutes to see which emails needs to be sent? A little more elaboration about your specific situation might help.

Answer (score 2):

Recipients don't matter, as long as you have access to a SMTP server.  Code looks something like this - you can get a whole lot more just by googling .NET send email:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
...

var msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("me@my.com");
msg.To.Add("you@yours.com");
msg.Subject = "Blah";
msg.Body = "Stuff";
var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpServerNameOrAddress");
smtp.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of server you are using,

for example if you are using Apache and PHP you can use SendMail for sending the mails

and if you are using ASP.NET, you can send it using any free SMTP Server like GMail

Here is a sample code :

```
SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.From = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("abc@def.com");
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.Body ="<p> Content Here </p>;
smtpobj.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpobj.Pot = 587;
smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
smtpobj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtpobj.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way mail clients send mail; they make a connection to an SMTP server and tell it to send the message. Some/most languages have built in support for that sort of thing; for example, PHP has the [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function

Comment: Thanks Michael for response. I'm trying to this in .NET. So far, I know we can send such email on gmail only but not on yahoo. is that correct, how do you send email to other than gmail ids?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) and [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) classes in .Net